# fastify searching data from postgresql

Tags: jquery, ajax, postgresql, search, fastify

login.ejs has following code

```
<input type="text" name="addUser_license" id="addUser_license" />

<!-- Display the search results -->

<ul>
  <% license_users.forEach((user2) => { %>
  <li><script> console.log("<%- user2.license_key %>");</script></li>
  <% }) %>
</ul>
```

and my ajax code is

```
$("#addUser_license").blur(function () {
        let myTxt = $(this).val();
        var formData = {
          "license_key": myTxt,
        };
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "JSON",
          url: "/license",
          data: formData,
        })
          .done(function (response) {
            console.log("Success: " + response.msg);
            console.log(data);
          })
          .fail(function (response) {
            console.log("Error: " + response.msg);
            console.log(myTxt);
            console.log(formData);
          });
      });
```

and my post request of server side is

```
fastify.post("/license", async (request, reply) => {
  const client = await fastify.pg.connect();
  const { license_key } = request.body;
  try {
    const result = await client.query(
      'SELECT * FROM license WHERE license_key LIKE $1',
      [license_key]
    );

    // Pass the search results to the EJS template
    reply.view( "/login.ejs", { license_users: result.rows } );
    console.log(result.rows)
    console.log(license_key)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return reply.view("error.ejs");
  } finally {
    client.release();
  }
});
```

following error occcur:

```
Error: undefined
```

and this line not works. Didn't any request to return

```
<li><script> console.log("<%- user2.license_key %>");</script></li>
```

and following console results fine show

console.log(result.rows)
console.log(license_key)

i think this line not works properly

```
reply.view( "/login.ejs", { license_users: result.rows } );
```

But i don't know why this not working? what should i do?

Comment: Return reply.view

Comment: still Error: undefined occured

Comment: Could you add the whole stack trace?